# Access Table Update fails on some computers

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

Okay, this is kind of odd and it is driving us nuts. I'll outline what is going on as best I can, then I can provide specific details and/or code as folks request it, because I'm not sure what will be needed to suss this out.

I have an access database I have built so our analysts can work within a queue, select records, do whatever research is needed, then either mark the record in question as okay, or fill in some blanks and mark it as needing a dispute (we work in billing).

Basically, the database opens and a hidden form pulls the NT User Name from the local machine, then opens a visible form that queries the database via SQL ODBC to display a list of records with that NT User Name attached to them.
The user can then scroll through the records, select them to get more information, and click a button to mark them as okay, or another to mark them as needing a dispute.

If they click the okay button, it fires off an update query to mark the record as okay. If they click the dispute button, then it opens a third form to show them the line item they are disputing with values from all of the other text fields on the form that they can select from/fill in. On that form there is a button to commit the dispute, which fires off another query to update the values into the same table as the 'okay' button.

So, the issue is, that this all works perfectly on my workhorse machine, and an essentially naked test machine. It also works on another co-worker's machine. However, whenever we try to run it on two other coworkers' machines, everything works just fine, except for any of the queries that attempt to write back to the ODBC connection. All of the read-only stuff works just fine, just not the updates. But the updates work perfectly, and super-fast on my machine, my test rig, and my other co-worker's machine.

We've tried reinstalling the ODBC connection, and the ODBC SQL Drivers.

*No go.*

We've tried just opening the table in question on the affected machines and making direct edits to the table.

*This works if no forms are open in the database, but as soon as we open a form, no update query will run against the table.*

So, we tried commenting out all code on all open forms except the docmd.openquery code for the single button we used to test the update query.

*No go.*

We even built a new form with just a button on it that triggers a new update query that makes only one simple update (Now()) to the table in question.

*This runs fine on its own, but times out when run off the button click from the form.*

We tried changing the MS Office install on one machine to 'run all from computer' to make sure all necessary components are installed/present.

*No go.*

We tried installing the ODBC connection both via the normal windows interface, and through the access linked table manager interface.

*No go.*

We tried installing both 64-bit and 32-bit ODBC connections, both under USER DSN and SYSTEM DSN, and all permutations of one and not the other that we could think of.

*No go.*

It seems that no update query will write to that table while any form is open, but works just fine with no forms open. But only on these other two machines. Everything works fine on the other three machines we've tested on, whether forms are open or not.

We're kind of at wit's end here and don't know where to go. Google is proving unhelpful, possibly because we just don't know exactly how to search the problem out.

Here's basic technical stuff and I am happy to provide whatever other details, code, queries, etc. that are needed to troubleshoot upon request:

**OS:** Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit

**Software:** MS Office Enterprise 2013 32-bit

**ODBC:** SQL Server

All users have admin access to their respective machines.

Comment: re: `...the docmd.openquery` in paragraph/section 9. Thats not VB.NET - sounds like access-vba (along with hidden forms etc to handle data). You may want to confirm and update the tags.

Comment: Too right. My bad. Updated. Thank you. :)

Comment: Almost sounds like authentication/permissions issue on SQL Server - NT based login?

Comment: We are using SQL Server authentication on the ODBC connection and all machines are using the same user name and password.

Comment: To us, it feels like a primary key issue. It's the same sort of lag you get, followed by an 'ODBC timeout' error dialogue. The one table in question, we have tried to disconnect and reconnect to see if we can make sure the primary key is properly selected, but when we reconnect to it, Access does not prompt us to select a primary key.

However, when we look at the table properties, the field we want as Primary key, is designated as such, since it is that way on the server.

It was originally created in Access, then pushed to the server, just like all of our other tables in this dB.

Comment: Does each user have their own local copy of the front-end database file?

Comment: Everyone is running local copies, yes. But they are the same version. So, no customized or individualized versions exist.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue here seems to have been an intermittent issue with Access being unable to determine which record to update due to the way we were calling details from a continuous form.

We went back to formula on our UI and built it so there is only ever one record on a form when we try to make changes to records, so there can be no system confusion about what record to update.

Still no clue as to why it was working intermittently, but the new iteration is working now.

Thank you all for your questions and suggestions. :)